# how to use two different controllers in a single route using node js

Tags: node.js

I am trying to sign-Up three different users `Admin`, `User`, `DeliveryPerson`. I have a `sign-Up` route in which all user can be use to sign-Up. But I have different controller for `DeliveryPerson` to sign-Up

this is my controller for `Admin` and `User` to `Sign-Up`

```
exports.signup = function(role){
    return function (req, res)  {
        const errors = validationResult(req);
    
        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
            return res.status(422).json({
                error: errors.array()[0].msg
            })
        } 
        const delivery = new Delivery(req.body)
        console.log(user);
        user.role = role;
        console.log(user);

        user.save((err, user) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(400).json({
                    error: "Unable to save User In DB"
                })
            }

            const token = jwt.sign({ _id: user._id }, process.env.SECRET);
            res.cookie("token", token, { expire: new Date() + 9999 });
            res.json({
                name: user.name,
                email: user.email,
                password: user.encry_password,
                id: user._id,
                token
            })
        })
    }
    }
```

this is my controller for `DeliveryPerson` to `Sign-Up`

```
exports.deliverySignUp = function(role){
    return function (req, res)  {
        const errors = validationResult(req);
    
        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
            return res.status(422).json({
                error: errors.array()[0].msg
            })
        } 
        const delivery = new Delivery(req.body);
        console.log(delivery);

        delivery.save((err, delivery) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(400).json({
                    error: "Unable to save Delivery Personnal In DB"
                })
            }

            const token = jwt.sign({ _id: delivery._id }, process.env.SECRET);
            res.cookie("token", token, { expire: new Date() + 9999 });
            res.json({
                name: delivery.name,
                email: delivery.email,
                password: delivery.encry_password,
                id: delivery._id,
                token
            })
        })
    }
    
}
```

Is there any way to use both this controllers in a single route?

Comment: check 'role' and just return if the it doesn't match.

Comment: @NikeLepz `user` and `admin` has same fields but `DeliveryPerson` has many filed that are not included in `user` and `admin`

Comment: that's even greater. You said you had different controller for 'deliveryGuy' only right?

Comment: @NikeLepz yes. but how to use them in same route

Comment: what im trying to say is, you keep your separate controllers, assign them to same routes, just check the role inside those controllers, and if the role doesn't match just call next() inside the middleware.

Comment: okay wait see if my answer helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this would work:

```js
//your controllers
function adminAndUserController(role) {
  return (req, res, next) => {
     if(role === "admin" || role === "user") {SomeStuffsIWannaDoWithUserAndAdmin()}
     else next();
  }
}

function deliveryGuyController(role) {
  return (req, res, next) => {
    if(role !== "deliveryGuy") return next();
    SomeStuffsIWannaDoWithDeliveryGuy();
  }
}

//now assign those controllers to the route
app.get('/auth/signUp', adminAndUserController(), deliveryGuyController());
```

Comment: ahh got it. So you are saying to use them as middleWares

Comment: umm well, I thought u were using them as ones in the beginning. I guess not.

Comment: I am using them like this
`
router.post("/admin/signup", [
    check("name", "name should be atleast 5 charater").isLength({ min: 5 }),
    check("email", "email is required").isEmail(),
    check("password", "password must be atleast 8 charater").isLength({ min: 8 }),
], signup(2))
`